# Exchange Web Services: Recover a deleted occurrence of a recurring series

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, exchangewebservices

**Situation:** A user creates a recurring event, this user deletes a single instance of the recurring event.

**Goal:** recover/restore the deleted instance to the calendar. Though actually I really just need to report on the cancelled instance (i.e. I look at a particular day for a user's calendar, how many meetings were cancelled vs scheduled).

For single appointments, when I do a `MoveToDeletedItems` delete or cancel action I can find that event in the `DeleteItems` folder and Move it back to the calendar or report on it.

However, occurrences of recurring series are treated differently. It seems like deleted occurrences (and all their data) are permanently deleted and the only trace is in the `RecurringMaster.DeletedOccurrences` but that only stores a `OriginalStart` property not title/description/attendees/etc.

All I figure I can to do is to merge info from the master recurring event (title/description/etc) with the original start to get a "deleted instance" appointment. Is this true? Note: this won't recover the right information if the instance was an `Exception` to the `RecurringMaster` appointment.

Note: this works pretty much the same for ews versions 2007 to 2013 (Office365)

*Search terms:
restore recover deleted cancelled instance occurrence recurring series recurringMaster DeletedOccurrences DeletedItems*

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I am having the same issue now. The instance does not get moved to the DeletedItems folder so we cant detect that its been deleted

Comment: No, basically don't expect to ever be able to recover deleted things from exchange. It can sort of be done but it's better to think of exchange as a system which only shows you active events as of right now (the current state).

Comment: To track deleted events, my current best solution is to compare syncing to a database. I sync a copy of events for some range t0 to t1 and then re-sync for an overlapping range t2 to t3. Then I look for everything between t2 and t1. Any events which are missing I store as deleted.